# Update State of Another Component Within A Generic Component Causes Warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

When designing a generic component, I adopted the principle of SOC where the generic component will not know the implementation details of the user and allow the user to listen for callbacks to handle their own state.

For example:

**SortButton.tsx**

```
interface Props {
  initialValue?: boolean;
  onToggle?: (value: boolean) => void;
}

const Toggle: React.FC<Props> = ({
  initialValue = false,
  onToggle,
}) => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = React.useState(initialValue);
  
  const handleToggle = React.useCallback(() => {
    let updatedValue = isActive;
    // do some computation if needed

    if(onToggle) {
      onSort(updatedValue);
    }

    setIsActive(updatedValue);
  }, [isActive, onToggle]);

  return (
    <div onClick={handleToggle}>Sort</div>
  );
}
```

**Parent.tsx**

```
  const Parent: React.FC<Props> = ({

  }) => {
    const [parentObject, setParentObject] = React.useState({});

    const handleToggle = React.useCallback((value: boolean) => {
       let updatedValue = value;
       // do some computation to updatedValue if needed

       setParentObject((parent) => { ...parent, calculated: updatedValue });
    }, []);

    return (
      <SortButton onToggle={handleToggle} />
    );
}
```

The above implementation allows the generic component (ie. Toggle) to handle their own state and allows parents to implement their own implementation using callbacks. However, I have been getting the following error:

```
Warning: Cannot update a component (`Parent`) while rendering a different component (`Toggle`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Toggle`
```

My understanding from the error is that, within the callback onClick, it triggers state mutation of the parent (in this case, another component) which should not be allowed. The solution I figured was to move the callback within an `useEffect` like this:

**SortButton.tsx**

```
interface Props {
  initialValue?: boolean;
  onToggle?: (value: boolean) => void;
}

const Toggle: React.FC<Props> = ({
  initialValue = false,
  onToggle,
}) => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = React.useState(initialValue);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let updatedValue = isActive;
    // do some computation if needed

    if(onToggle) {
      onSort(updatedValue);
    }

  }, [isActive, onToggle]);
  
  const handleToggle = React.useCallback(() => {
    setIsActive((value) => !value);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div onClick={handleToggle}>Sort</div>
  );
}
```

The new implementation works but I have a few questions which I would hope to get some guidance on.

1. The example works and is easy to refactor because it is a simple state of isActive. What if the value we need is more complicated (for example, mouse position, etc) and does not have a state to store the value and is only available from onMouseMove? Do we create a state to store the `mouse position and follow the pattern?
2. Is the existing implementation an anti-pattern to any of the React concepts in the first place?
3. Is there any other possible implementation to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is a somewhat biased opinion, but I'm a big proponent of [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and ["Dumb" Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0)/[Controlled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

I would design it so that the `SortButton` does not have any internal state.  It would get all of the information that it needs from props.  The `Parent` would be responsible for passing down the correct value of `isActive`/`value`, which it will update when the child `SortButton` calls its `onToggle` prop.

We can include the event in the `onToggle` callback just in case the parent wants to use it.

**SortButton.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";

interface Props {
  isActive: boolean;
  onToggle: (value: boolean, e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => void;
}

const Toggle: React.FC<Props> = ({ isActive, onToggle }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={isActive ? "sort-active" : "sort-inactive"}
      onClick={(e) => onToggle(!isActive, e)}
    >
      {isActive ? "Unsort" : "Sort"}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Toggle;
```

**Parent.tsx**

```
import * as React from "react";
import SortButton from "./SortButton";

interface Props {
  list: number[];
}

const Parent: React.FC<Props> = ({ list }) => {
  // parent stores the state of the sort
  const [isSorted, setIsSorted] = React.useState(false);

  // derived data is better as a memo than as state.
  const sortedList = React.useMemo(
    // either sort the list or don't.
    () => (isSorted ? [...list].sort() : list),
    // depends on the list prop and the isSorted state.
    [list, isSorted]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <SortButton
        isActive={isSorted}
        // you could use a more complicated callback, but it's not needed here.
        onToggle={setIsSorted}
      />
      <ul>
        {sortedList.map((n) => (
          <li>{n.toFixed(3)}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

[Code Sandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-controlled-component-sort-button-86c78?file=/src/Parent.tsx)

Comment: +1 Thanks Linda. I agree that lifting the state would take out unnecessary complexity - making the component dumb. The part that I do not understand is that in both methods (passing the state in or not), the onToggle function technically mutates the state of the parent in which the error suggests. Could you explain further on the difference?  And if my implementation is anti-pattern or unadvisable.